# Flutter: How to get my location high accuracy?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, geolocation

```
Future<Position> mylocation() async{
  Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy:LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);

  return position;
}
```

I want to get my location. but sometime `mylocation` get wrong position. How to get my location high accuracy?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
```

Comment: As far as I know `best` and `bestForNavigation` is same at android.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the location high accuracy you can use

```
Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

Make sure to adjust the accuracy and read the docs to fit your use case.